# React component only rendering one item in my object

Tags: reactjs

So I have a react component set up to map through all the items in my array to display them on the page. I'm importing my component onto my homepage and passing the object as a prop from the imported component. However, when I load the page, only one item from the object is being rendered. I'm not entirely sure if I'm passing my object correctly. Any help would be appreciated! Code is below.

This is my Modal component. I'm mapping through the listGroupArray that has a spread operator with my data that is being passed from the home page.

```
export default function ModalButton({ setData, title, arrayData, dataTitle }) {
    
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [button, setButton] = useState("Choose...")

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    const listGroupArray = [{...arrayData}]

    const changeButton = e => setButton(e)

    return (
        <>
        <h5 className="inputFont text-center">{title}</h5>
        <Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: "1", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} variant="primary" className="w-100 mb-4 inputFont" onClick={handleShow}>
            {button}
        </Button>
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton className="modal-bg inputFont">
                {dataTitle}
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body className="modal-bg">
                <ListGroup>
            {listGroupArray.map(item => (
              <ListGroup.Item key={item.id} className="modal-bg">
                <Button
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "black",
                    opacity: ".8",
                    color: "white",
                    borderColor: "red",
                  }}
                  className="inputFont w-100"
                  name={item.name}
                  value={item.value}
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    setData(item.value);
                    changeButton(item.name);
                    handleClose();
                  }}
                >
                  {item.name}
                </Button>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            ))}
          </ListGroup>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
    );
}
```

This is my homepage where I'm passing the array data as an object. I'm pretty sure this is where I'm going wrong. When I load the page, the component should render all the data in the object, however it's only rendering the last data, Classics.

```
                                        <Modal title="Genre" 
                                        dataTitle="Pick A Genre"
                                        setData={setGenrelist}
                                        arrayData={
                                            
                                                {
                                                id: 1,
                                                name: "Action and Adventure",
                                                value: "10673,10702,11804,11828,1192487,1365,1568,2125,2653,43040,43048,4344,46576,7442,75418,76501,77232,788212,801362,899,9584"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    id: 2,
                                                    name: "Musicals",
                                                    value: "13335,13573,32392,52852,55774,59433,84488,88635"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    id: 3,
                                                    name: "Sci-Fi",
                                                    value: "1492,108533,11014,1372,1568,1694,2595,2729,3327,3916,47147,4734,49110,50232,52780,52849,5903,6000,6926,852491"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    id: 4,
                                                    name: "Fantasy",
                                                    value: "9744"
                                                },
                                                {   id: 5,
                                                    name: "Thrillers",
                                                    value: "10306,10499,10504,10719,11014,11140,1138506,1321,1774,3269,43048,46588,5505,58798,65558,6867,75390,78507,799,852488,8933,98911,9147,972"
                                                },
                                                {   
                                                    id:  6,
                                                    name: "Anime",
                                                    value: "10695,11146,2653,2729,3063,413820,452,6721,9302,7424"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    id: 7,
                                                    name: "Children and Family",
                                                    value: "10056,27480,27950,28034,28083,28233,48586,5455,561,6218,6796,6962,78120,89513,783"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    id: 8,
                                                    name: "Comedies",
                                                    value: "1009,10256,10375,105,10778,11559,11755,1208951,1333288,1402,1747,17648,2030,2700,31694,3300,34157,3519,3996,4058,4195,43040,4426,4906,52104,52140,52847,5286,5475,5610,56174,58905,59169,61132,61330,6197,63092,63115,6548,711366,7120,72407,7539,77599,77907,78163,78655,79871,7992,852492,869,89585,9302,9434,9702,9736"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    id: 9,
                                                    name: "Documentaries",
                                                    value: "10005,10105,10599,1159,15456,180,2595,2616,2760,28269,3652,3675,4006,4720,48768,49110,49547,50232,5161,5349,55087,56178,58710,60026,6839,7018,72384,77245,852494,90361,9875"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    id: 10,
                                                    name: "Dramas",
                                                    value: "11,11075,11714,1208954,1255,12995,13158,2150,25955,26009,2696,2748,2757,2893,29809,3179,31901,34204,3653,3682,384,3916,3947,4282,4425,452,4961,500,5012,52148,52904,56169,58755,58796,59064,6206,62235,6616,6763,68699,6889,711367,71591,71591,72354,7243,7539,75459,76507,78628,852493,89804,9299,9847,9873,5763"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    id: 11,
                                                    name: "Sports",
                                                    value: "180,25788,4370,5286,7243,9327"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    id: 12,
                                                    name: "Horror",
                                                    value: "10695,10944,1694,42023,45028,48303,61546,75405,75804,75930,8195,83059,8711,89585"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    id: 13,
                                                    name: "Romance",
                                                    value: "29281,36103,502675"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    id: 14,
                                                    name: "Classics",
                                                    value: "10032,11093,13158,29809,2994,31273,31574,31694,32392,46553,46560,46576,46588,47147,47465,48303,48586,48744,76186"
                                                }
                                            
                                            } 
                                
                                        />
```

[screenshot of the homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4Yov.jpg)
This image shows the component only rendering one data item which is Classics. Any advice on how to get all data rendered would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try to remove the brackets when spreading `arrayData` into `listGroupArray` like this. `[...arrayData]`

Comment: I tried removing brackets and it threw an error saying arrayData is not iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in how you referenced the `arrayData` and the problematic curly brackets you used on an array. In your JSX code, you have a syntax error, you are supposed to enclose arrays in curly brackets, or better still just separate them to their own variable.

Your JSX should then look something like this:

```
function JSX(props) {
  const arrayData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Action and Adventure",
      value:
        "10673,10702,11804,11828,1192487,1365,1568,2125,2653,43040,43048,4344,46576,7442,75418,76501,77232,788212,801362,899,9584",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Musicals",
      value: "13335,13573,32392,52852,55774,59433,84488,88635",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Sci-Fi",
      value:
        "1492,108533,11014,1372,1568,1694,2595,2729,3327,3916,47147,4734,49110,50232,52780,52849,5903,6000,6926,852491",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Fantasy",
      value: "9744",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Thrillers",
      value:
        "10306,10499,10504,10719,11014,11140,1138506,1321,1774,3269,43048,46588,5505,58798,65558,6867,75390,78507,799,852488,8933,98911,9147,972",
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "Anime",
      value: "10695,11146,2653,2729,3063,413820,452,6721,9302,7424",
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: "Children and Family",
      value:
        "10056,27480,27950,28034,28083,28233,48586,5455,561,6218,6796,6962,78120,89513,783",
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: "Comedies",
      value:
        "1009,10256,10375,105,10778,11559,11755,1208951,1333288,1402,1747,17648,2030,2700,31694,3300,34157,3519,3996,4058,4195,43040,4426,4906,52104,52140,52847,5286,5475,5610,56174,58905,59169,61132,61330,6197,63092,63115,6548,711366,7120,72407,7539,77599,77907,78163,78655,79871,7992,852492,869,89585,9302,9434,9702,9736",
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      name: "Documentaries",
      value:
        "10005,10105,10599,1159,15456,180,2595,2616,2760,28269,3652,3675,4006,4720,48768,49110,49547,50232,5161,5349,55087,56178,58710,60026,6839,7018,72384,77245,852494,90361,9875",
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      name: "Dramas",
      value:
        "11,11075,11714,1208954,1255,12995,13158,2150,25955,26009,2696,2748,2757,2893,29809,3179,31901,34204,3653,3682,384,3916,3947,4282,4425,452,4961,500,5012,52148,52904,56169,58755,58796,59064,6206,62235,6616,6763,68699,6889,711367,71591,71591,72354,7243,7539,75459,76507,78628,852493,89804,9299,9847,9873,5763",
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      name: "Sports",
      value: "180,25788,4370,5286,7243,9327",
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      name: "Horror",
      value:
        "10695,10944,1694,42023,45028,48303,61546,75405,75804,75930,8195,83059,8711,89585",
    },
    {
      id: 13,
      name: "Romance",
      value: "29281,36103,502675",
    },
    {
      id: 14,
      name: "Classics",
      value:
        "10032,11093,13158,29809,2994,31273,31574,31694,32392,46553,46560,46576,46588,47147,47465,48303,48586,48744,76186",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Modal
      title="Genre"
      dataTitle="Pick A Genre"
      setData={(data) => console.log(data)}
      arrayData={arrayData}
    />
  );
}
```

The next bug you had was in using the spread operator. While arrays *are technically objects in JavaScript* they can't be spread with curly braces. This `[{...arrayData}]` is syntactically incorrect. Instead it should be `[...arrayData]`. With these in place, your code should run correctly.

I made a sandbox of your code in a working state for reference, check it out here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/young-snowflake-efqwk?file=/src/ModalButton.js:877-883

Comment: Thanks @TrentonMcKinney, I included the essential errors in the answer.